# Keep indentation level for included Twig subtemplate

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working with the Twig template engine and want to include a sub-template linke the following example:

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    {% include 'menu.twig' %}
  </div>
</header>
```

The included file contains the following code:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Now Twig generates the followig HTML code:

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

As you can see the indentation level is only correct for the first line of the included file which leads to the code above which is quite untidy and bad to maintain.

How is it possible to get a correct output from Twig with correct indentation like this?

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to maintain indentation when including templates. The only solution I can imagine would be to pass the indentation level in a variable and use a loop in the included template to prefix that amount of whitespaces in each line. Obviously this "solution" would be crazy and a nightmare to maintain.

Regarding this comment: "[...] which leads to the code above which is quite untidy and bad to maintain." I'd like to say the following:

- It doesn't matter if the HTML is "untidy". Browsers won't complain and users won't see it.
- It's true that it's bad to maintain. Luckily, you maintain the beautifully aligned Twig template, not the generated HTML code.

All the above would be different if the Twig template was generating a format where "perfect alignment" is mandatory. But in the case of HTML, please don't waste your time aligning the tags.

Comment: Though it is true that most users won't see it, I often will look at the HTML of pages that I admire to see what I can glean from them to use in my own web pages.  If the HTML is badly formatted (such as all on one line or with confusing indentation) than I have a hard time gleaning anything from them.  When I make my web pages, I would like them to be well-formatted so that others can learn from my code.  I don't consider it a waste at all.

Comment: Thats the point why I also like proper indentation. I wonder why it's so difficult for Twig. It just needs to keep the indentation level for all lines in the included file (not just the first one) and everything would be fine.

Comment: This is true, and is probably not a twig-specific issue as there are many templating engines out there which most likely have the same issue.  Template engines in general are intended for the code you write and not the HTML they generate.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to maintain the exact indentation of the included sub-template, you can do this:

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
{% include 'menu.twig' %}
  </div>
</header>
```

i.e. put all the "include" directives at the beginning of the line. The result will be:

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

But somehow I feel this is not good enough. 
Another solution is to add the indentation in the sublayout, i.e.

```
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
```

but of course it only works if the sublayout is always included at a certain level of indentation.

I suggest you take a completely different route and format the response **after** it is generated, e.g. with a listener on the kernel.response event.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Twig filter like this after creating your twig environment in php:

```
$filter = new Twig_Filter('ident', function ($string, $number) {
    $spaces = str_repeat(' ', $number);
    return rtrim(preg_replace('#^(.+)$#m', sprintf('%1$s$1', $spaces), $string));
}, array('is_safe' => array('all')));

$Your_Twig_Environment->addFilter($filter);
```

after this you can use it like this :

```
{{ include('menu.twig')|ident(4) }}
```

(be careful use include function syntax with {{ }} and not include tag syntax {% %})